# How can I get all text in an SVG document that's exactly within a rectangular region?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a complex SVG document generated from a PDF research paper via PDF.js, and I want to find all text within a rectangular area. This is in support of a web-based labeling tool where users can draw rectangles on top of arbitrary regions of the rendered SVG file (basically treating it as an image) and need to see the corresponding text. The first approach I thought of is iterating through each of the SVG's `svg:text` or `svg:tspan` elements and checking whether it intersects with the rectangle in question, perhaps using [checkEnclosure()](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__checkEnclosure) ([unsupported by FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_1.1_Support_in_Firefox), BTW).

However, this won't work for cases where the rectangle annotates characters that are a subset of a `svg:text` or `svg:tspan`. For example, imagine that we want to annotate individual keywords in this line:

> *Keywords:* Heusler alloys; Pressure effect; Curie temperature

The SVG in this case breaks it into two 's (because 'Keywords ' is italics):

> 'Keywords: '

and

> 'Heusler alloys; Pressure effect; Curie temperature'

If one rect is drawn around just the words 'Pressure effect', the program would essentially need to scan each character in each  and look for its intersection with the rect (more specifically, is fully contained by it). In this way it would basically treat each char as a rectangular glyph.

It would really help if you would share some pointers, either based on this initial approach or on something else you know about.

**Update 2015-07-23:**

Following are the W3 SVG DOM methods of interest that I could find:

[InterfaceSVGSVGElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#InterfaceSVGSVGElement) - *interface that corresponds to the ‘svg’ element*

- boolean checkEnclosure(in SVGElement element, in SVGRect rect)
- boolean checkIntersection(in SVGElement element, in SVGRect rect)
- NodeList getEnclosureList(in SVGRect rect, in SVGElement
  referenceElement)
- NodeList getIntersectionList(in SVGRect rect, in SVGElement referenceElement)

[InterfaceSVGTextContentElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#InterfaceSVGTextContentElement) - *inherited by various text-related interfaces, such as SVGTextElement, SVGTSpanElement, SVGTRefElement, SVGAltGlyphElement and SVGTextPathElement.*

- SVGRect getExtentOfChar(in unsigned long charnum);

[InterfaceSVGLocatable](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable) - *for all elements which either have a ‘transform’ attribute or don't have a ‘transform’ attribute but whose content can have a bounding box in current user space*

- SVGRect getBBox()

Comment: Use `getBBox()` on _all_ `svg:text` and `svg:tspan` then create a library of these rectangles. So the task is simplified to: which rectangle intersects with the drawn rectangle.